# Error Eigean file while installing ROS

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am building my robot and when i try to installed ROS on Raspbian i had this error

---

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
of the following names:

Eigen3Config.cmake
eigen3-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Eigen3"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'pcl_ros':
Command '['/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
 cd /Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros && /Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/robert/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

---

So can anyone help me and tells me how to fix it? i looked for answers but non of them seems to solve this for me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279704/error-eigean-file-while-installing-ros/) by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2018-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-12**:
What version of ROS, what version of Raspbian, how are you trying to install it, what answers did you try but didn't work?

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-13**:
I am using ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi, http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi
and when i follow the steps provided here i will have this error when i try to build the workspace

**Comment by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) on 2018-01-13**:
i solved the problem by copying the FindEigen3.cmake from cmake.2.8 to cmake.3.6 i think the new version of cmake dont have the FindEigen3.cmake and that what was causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i solved the problem by copying the FindEigen3.cmake from cmake.2.8 to cmake.3.6
i think the new version of cmake dont have the FindEigen3.cmake and that what was causing the problem.

now i am having error with gazeboConfig.cmake can not be found, which i will try to solve.

thank you

---

Originally posted by [Mohammedism](https://answers.ros.org/users/32825/mohammedism/) with karma: 32 on 2018-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1